# How to rotate a pdf file "really" using iText7

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, itext7

I want to rotate a pdf file clockwise and keep the rotated boxes of the page.The official example code:

```
      PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(dest));
            for (int p = 1; p <= pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); p++) 
            {
                PdfPage page = pdfDoc.GetPage(p);
                int rotate = page.GetRotation();
                if (rotate == 0) {
                    page.SetRotation(90);
                }
                else 
                {
                    page.SetRotation((rotate + 90) % 360);
                }
            }
            pdfDoc.Close();
```

It seems that it only sets a rotation data in every page.I want to rotate it and keep Rotation=0.

With [srcfile](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AqxJcIfHZ18UiQSHkPrNSPh0O5Dj?e=Tjgfzu),i got the result [I wanted](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AqxJcIfHZ18UiQZVr5A4tmBLa-u5?e=u9oZmn) with code:

```
string src = @"-x-y_28P_src.pdf";
string targetFPath = @"-x-y_28P_real_rotated.pdf";
using (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(targetFPath)))
using (PdfDocument origPdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src)))
{
    pdfDoc.GetWriter().SetSmartMode(true);
    int pageCount = origPdf.GetNumberOfPages();
    for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
    {
        PdfPage origPage = origPdf.GetPage(i);
        var pageCopy = origPage.CopyAsFormXObject(pdfDoc);
        var mediaBox = origPage.GetMediaBox();//x = -8.5,y=-8.5
        var cropBox = origPage.GetCropBox();
        var trimBox = origPage.GetTrimBox();
        var mediaRect90 = new Rectangle(0, 0, mediaBox.GetHeight(), mediaBox.GetWidth());//media:0,0,h,w,data from pdfinfo of xpdf.
        var page = pdfDoc.AddNewPage(new PageSize(mediaRect90));//media:0,0,h,w
        var canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
        canvas.AddXObject(pageCopy, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0 - mediaBox.GetBottom(), mediaBox.GetRight());//Clockwise

        var cropbox = new Rectangle(0, 0, cropBox.GetHeight(), cropBox.GetWidth());
        page.SetCropBox(cropbox);
        var trimbox = new Rectangle(-mediaBox.GetBottom(), -mediaBox.GetLeft(), trimBox.GetHeight(), trimBox.GetWidth());
        page.SetTrimBox(trimbox);//important
    }
}
```

For [the other file](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AqxJcIfHZ18UiQNcgTL6BBMtkq5-?e=k188gU), I can't get [the correct result](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AqxJcIfHZ18UiQJvubzSreb62GNt?e=qO7srE) no matter how I try.

In addition, the method I implemented seems to be a little complicated.

Is there any way to deal with it.

Comment: @mkl Is there any way?

Comment: @zhusp  *"Is there any way?"* - of course there is. But the complete general solution is clearly non-trivial, in particular if annotations and destinations are involved.

Comment: Thanks for reply! If we  don't consider annotations and destinations, just apply a matrix?

Comment: If you only want to consider the static content of the pages, you just need to prepend a rotating transformation matrix (maybe including a translation) and adapt the boxes (media box, crop box, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Changing a PDF for rotation will usually involve a rewrite of some parts of page data. So here is the above source and desire, expanded to show some possible differences that would need revolving/resolving in a fresh rebuild.

[image]

Noticeably when PDFs are rewritten, the objects often change relative position, so object 2 on the left became object 3 on the right, whilst not essential they become a new order it is certainly very common.

Another very common difference is that units are usually recalculated so in one case 0.9 becomes .9 and in another the rotated page dimensions become a different precision from 595.28 in one to 595.280029296 in the other. Every generation, just like genetic mutation, can have different character-istics.

Whist the OP question is for iText the steps that need to be considered as here using cpdf as it simpler to see the logic.

Cpdf has a normalise function to ensure the page is at a common origin and at its default rotation, thus we can pre-set all the content to 0 upright, so that full rotation is easier and importantly safer, or we can do it later, however it will in this case disturb the viewport set by the /TrimBox so that needs close monitoring.

***Before***

```
Page 1:
Label:
MediaBox: -8.503940 -8.503940 603.780000 850.394000
CropBox: -8.503940 -8.503940 603.780000 850.394000
BleedBox: -8.503940 -8.503940 603.780000 850.394000
TrimBox: 0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000
ArtBox: 8.503940 8.503940 586.772000 833.386000
Rotation: 0
```

***After cpdf -upright***

```
Page 1:
Label:
MediaBox: 0.000000 0.000000 612.283940 858.897940
CropBox: 0.000000 0.000000 612.283940 858.897940
BleedBox: 0.000000 0.000000 612.283940 858.897940
TrimBox: 8.503940 8.503940 603.779940 850.393940
ArtBox: 17.007880 17.007880 595.275940 841.889940
Rotation: 0
```

Now we can consider pivoting 90 degrees clockwise around the 0,0 axis

`-rotateby 90 "upright.pdf" -o "rotated.pdf"`

which will naturally report

```
Page 1:
Label:
MediaBox: 0.000000 0.000000 612.283940 858.897940
CropBox: 0.000000 0.000000 612.283940 858.897940
BleedBox: 0.000000 0.000000 612.283940 858.897940
TrimBox: 8.503940 8.503940 603.779940 850.393940
ArtBox: 17.007880 17.007880 595.275940 841.889940
Rotation: 90
```

At this point we can set that it is upright again, we are getting closer, the orientation is now as if landscape, but content is unconventionally read from left (standard convention for drawings  etc. is read from right) *"If you already have a lot of text laid out, make it so that it can be read from the right side after you rotate."* CADD / Charting / Diagrams **ORIENT**ation is 0 to right (eastern orient) and 90 ccw upright to polar zenith (so 90 = anti-clockwise).

`-upright "rotated.pdf" -o penultimate.pdf`

***After***

```
Page 1:
Label:
MediaBox: 0.000000 0.000000 858.897940 612.283940
CropBox: 0.000000 0.000000 858.897940 612.283940
BleedBox: 0.000000 0.000000 858.897940 612.283940
TrimBox: 8.503940 8.504000 850.393940 603.780000
ArtBox: 17.007880 17.008000 841.889940 595.276060
Rotation: 0
```

Finally, we can reset the crop box to a new viewer origin of 8.504 8.504 and desired width and height 841.890 and 595.276 and the result is 0 upside-down reading rotated clockwise.pdf

[image]

**So for the second more troublesome case steps are similar depending on info**

`cpdf -page-info "custom_xy_src.pdf" 1`  shows

```
Page 1:
Label:
MediaBox: 0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000
CropBox: 12.000000 6.000000 592.276000 832.890000
BleedBox:
TrimBox:
ArtBox:
Rotation: 0
```

good its already upright but again its not well defined lets normalise by remove that cropbox

`cpdf -remove-cropbox "custom_xy_src.pdf" -o normalised.pdf`
now its safe to rotate
`cpdf -rotateby 90 normalised.pdf -o rotated90.pdf`
and in this simpler case just reset the upside-down file as if upright
`cpdf -upright "rotated90.pdf" -o "finished.pdf"`
and now we have a different yet similar outcome
[image]

```
Page 1:
Label:
MediaBox: 0.000000 0.000000 841.890000 595.276000
CropBox:
BleedBox:
TrimBox:
ArtBox:
Rotation: 0
```

*Lastly if you want the undersized result as per question desire we need to replace*

```
CropBox: 12.000000 6.000000 592.276000 832.890000
```

as 6.000000 12.000000 832.890000 592.276000

However, I suggest you do NOT as its then not a standard ISO A4 page

**In summary although both sources have similar appearance both need totally different solutions to appear the same.**

Comment: Thanks @K J.Is there a code solution using Itext7?